# Number staircase - nested for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make

[image: this]

using only nested loop and if statement.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    if (j < i) {
      document.write(j + " ");
    }
  }
  document.write("<br>");
}
```

However, the output is different to what I want (try running the snippet).

Comment: Very cool! What seems to be the issue? (See also: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: You probably need to do some multiplication in there. Something akin to: i*j. Structure is correct. Just need to add the math part.

Comment: As @SherylHohman says, the problem is that you need to reconsider what it is you're actually printing; the output format etc. is fine, just the actual number is wrong. Instead of printing `j`, what is it you need to print? Try a few examples of `i`,`j` and expected output, it should be obvious what's going on! Also, as a deleted comment mentioned, you can change the inner loop condition to avoid needing the `if` - can you see how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the value of `i` to calculate the number you are going to print

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      document.write((i-1)*j + " ");        
  }
  document.write("<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This way you won't need the IF statement:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        document.write(j * i, ' ')
    }
    document.write('<br>')
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your code to conform to requirements ("just for loops"), but otherwise this seems to be the correct answer.